# Adding Image to Class

Tags: java, image, class

I'm currently working on a FIFA draft simulator, and so I created a class for each player:

```
public class Player {
    public Player(int rating, int id, String country, String position, String club, String league, Image card) 
    {
    }
}
```

However, when I try to make an image to then add to a `Player`, it doesn't work

```
Image ronaldo_card = new Image("ronaldo.png");
```

IntelliJ says

> 'Image' is abstract; cannot be intialized

How should I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ImageIO`, as below:

```
try {
    File ronaldoPhotoFile = new File("ronaldo.png");
    Image ronaldo_card = ImageIO.read(ronaldoPhotoFile);
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have a look at this:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/index.html

As said in the example, you can load a picture that way:

```
 BufferedImage img = null;
 try {
     img = ImageIO.read(new File("strawberry.jpg"));
 } catch (IOException e) {
 }
```

Good luck for your project ! :)